# Laravel query order with order_details using id

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, eloquent

Stuck on this.
I use this same query without Id to get all the successfully get all this data.

```
$orders = $this->order
    ->with('orderDetails', 'orderDetails.product')
    ->today()
    ->get();
```

Relationships

Order:

```
public function orderDetails(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\OrderDetail', 'order_id');
}
```

OrderDetail:

```
 public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Order', 'order_id', 'id');
}

public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'id_products', 'id');
}
```

But trying to use the same thing to get data for a particular order doesn't return the order_details.

```
   public function invoice(Request $request, $id)
  {
    $ordered = $this->order
        ->find($id)
        ->with('orderDetails', 'orderDetails.product');

   return response()->json($ordered);
  }
```

Why is it behaving differently when passed an id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `find` the query is executed before other directives. You need to be using `where`:

```
$ordered = $this->order
    ->where('order_id', $id)
    ->with('orderDetails', 'orderDetails.product')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to use just this way:

```
$ordered = $this->order->find($id);

return response()->json($ordered);
```

The laravel already turned to relationships based on no mapping that you enter in the model.
In this case, your orderDetails in your response will look like this:

Order: {
Id: "1",
Xpto: "whatever",
OrderDetails: {
Id: "1"
}
}

Comment: I tried it this way already and it doesn't come with the orderDetails. Only returns that order.